# Scrolling with multiple controls in panel C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a Form with 4 Controls. One panel, which contains 2 DataGridViews and 1 Label. First there is a datagridview, then the label and then the last datagridview. The Form has a specific size like 600x400. I also want that the first datagridview should have the exact height of all cell height + header cell height from the first datagridview. If its bigger than 400, there should be a scrollbar on the right. If the user scrolls down, he should the the label and the 2. DataGridView. If the Height is less than 400, maybe 300, then it should show already the label and a scrollbar on the right. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Panel control has a property called "AutoScroll" that you can set to true (in the properties pane while you are in design mode.)  This will handle showing and hiding the scrollbar based on the size of the child controls.  Make sure that the panel has a fixed height, rather than using AutoSize.

If I am understanding correctly, you want the first DataGridView to size itself based on the size of its contents.  To do that, just set AutoSize = true on the DataGridView and it will resize based on its contents.

If you want more specific help, you can post your code and what you have tried, and you may get a better answer.